# Design L1 and L2 distance functions to assess the similarity of bank customers. Each customer is characterized by the following attribute

Tags: algorithm, distance, knn

I am having a hard time with the question below. I am not sure if I got it correct, but either way, I need some help futher understanding it if anyone has time to explain, please do.

Design L1 and L2 distance functions to assess the similarity of bank customers. Each customer is characterized by the following attributes:
−   Age (customer’s age, which is a real number with the maximum age is 90 years and minimum age 15 years)
−   Cr (“credit rating”) which is ordinal attribute with values ‘very good’, ‘good, ‘medium’, ‘poor’, and ‘very poor’.
−   Av_bal  (avg account balance, which is a real number with mean 7000, standard deviation is 4000)

1. Using the L1 distance function computes the distance between the following 2 customers: c1 = (55, good, 7000) and c2 = (25, poor, 1000). [15 points]

Using the L2 distance function computes the distance between the above mentioned 2 customers

Using the L2 distance function computes the distance between the above mentioned 2 customers.
Answer with L1

d(c1,c2) = (c1.cr-c2.cr)/4 +(c1.avg.bal –c2.avg.bal/4000)* (c1.age-mean.age/std.age)-( c2.age-mean.age/std.age)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as is, leaves some room for interpretation. Mainly because similarity is not specified exactly. I will try to explain what the standard approach would be.

Usually, before you start, you want to normalize values such that they are rougly in the same range. Otherwise, your similarity will be dominated by the feature with the largest variance.

If you have no information about the distribution but just the range of the values you want to try to nomalize them to [0,1]. For your example this means

> norm_age = (age-15)/(90-15)

For nominal values you want to find a mapping to ordinal values if you want to use L<sub>p</sub>-Norms. Note: this is not always possible (e.g., colors cannot intuitively be mapped to ordinal values). In you case you can transform the credit rating like this

cr = {0 if ‘very good’, 1 if ‘good, 2 if ‘medium’, 3 if ‘poor’, 4 if ‘very poor’}

afterwards you can do the same normalization as for age

> norm_cr = cr/4

Lastly, for normally distributed values you usually perform standardization by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.

> norm_av_bal = (av_bal-7000)/4000

Now that you have normalized your values, you can go ahead and define the distance functions:

> L1(c1, c2) = |c1.norm_age - c2.norm_age| + |c1.norm_cr - c2.norm_cr |
>   +             |c1.norm_av_bal - c2.norm_av_bal|

and

> L2(c1, c2) = sqrt((c1.norm_age - c2.norm_age)<sup>2</sup> + (c1.norm_cr -
>   c2.norm_cr)<sup>2</sup> + (c1.norm_av_bal -
>   c2.norm_av_bal)<sup>2</sup>)